# Preventing image and text on a page from moving on resize

Tags: html, css

below I've posted my CSS and HTML, I am specifically trying to prevent the text and image from moving when resizing the page. At the moment, if you run the snippet you'll see if the window is resized then you're able to see the image/text moving. Anyone ideas on how to to efficiently approach this? I would like to keep them positioned strictly despite the window resize.

```css
html, body, div, span, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
abbr, address, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, samp,
small, strong, sub, sup, var,
b, i,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    border:0;
    outline:0;
    font-size:100%;
    vertical-align:baseline;
    background:transparent;
}

body {
    line-height:1;
}

article,aside,details,figcaption,figure,
footer,header,hgroup,menu,nav,section { 
    display:block;
}

nav ul {
    list-style:none;
}

blockquote, q {
    quotes:none;
}

blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content:'';
    content:none;
}

a {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    font-size:100%;
    vertical-align:baseline;
    background:transparent;
}

/* change colours to suit your needs */
ins {
    background-color:#ff9;
    color:#000;
    text-decoration:none;
}

/* change colours to suit your needs */
mark {
    background-color:#ff9;
    color:#000; 
    font-style:italic;
    font-weight:bold;
}

del {
    text-decoration: line-through;
}

abbr[title], dfn[title] {
    border-bottom:1px dotted;
    cursor:help;
}

table {
    border-collapse:collapse;
    border-spacing:0;
}

/* change border colour to suit your needs */
hr {
    display:block;
    height:1px;
    border:0;   
    border-top:1px solid #cccccc;
    margin:1em 0;
    padding:0;
}

input, select {
    vertical-align:middle;
}

/******* RESET FINISHED BEYOND THIS POINT ******/

#header{
 background-color:#2098D1;
 color:white;
 padding-top:30px;

}

.group-wrapper{
 width:60%;
 margin:0 auto;
 overflow:hidden;
 position:relative;

 
}

.logo-name{
 line-height:1.4;
 display:inline-block;
 vertical-align: middle;
 font-family:arial;
 position:relative;
 float:left;
}

.logo-name h1{
 font-size:20px;
 text-transform: uppercase;

}

.logo-name h2{
 font-size:15px;
 font-weight:normal;

}

#nav{
 float:right;
 

}

#nav ul{
 float:right;
 width:100%;
 font-family:arial;


}

#nav ul li{
 display:inline-block;
 margin-right:10px;
 font-size: 15px;
}


.intro-company{
 background-color:#2098D1;
 color:white;
 padding-top:30px;
 height:250px;
}

.group-center{
 width: 60%;
 margin:0 auto;
 position:relative;
 text-align:center;
 margin-top:30px;
}


.group-center h1{
 font-size:48px;
 font-family:arial;
}

.group-center h2{
 font-family:arial;
 font-weight:normal;
 font-size:23px;
 margin-top:20px;
}

.group-center h3{
 font-family:arial;
 font-weight:bold;
 font-size:13px;
 margin-top:30px;
}


.content-wrapper{
 width:70%;
 margin:0 auto;
}

.main-content h1{
 text-align:center;
 font-family:Arial;
 font-size:50px; 
}

.main-content span{
 font-weight: bold;
 color:#2098D1;
}

.content-wrapper{
 overflow:hidden;
 margin-top:50px;
}
.content-wrapper img{
 float:left;
 width:25%;

 
}

.main-content{
 overflow:hidden;

}

.content-wrapper p{
 margin-top:20px;
 width:75%;
 margin-left:25%;
 line-height: 1.3em;
 font-family:arial;
 text-align:center;
 font-size:20px;
}


/****** MEDIA QUERIES ******/

@media screen and (min-width:1200px)
     and (max-width:1600px){

  .main-content h1{
 text-align:center;
 font-family:Arial;
 font-size:35px; 
}
.content-wrapper p{
 margin-top:20px;
 width:75%;
 margin-left:25%;
 line-height: 1.3em;
 font-family:arial;
 text-align:center;
 font-size:19px;

}
    



}



/****** SCREEN: 1115PX ******/
@media screen and (max-width: 1115px) {
#nav{
 float:none;

}

#nav ul{
 float:none;
}

#nav ul li{
 display:inline-block;
 margin-right:10px;
 font-size: 10px;
 
 

}

.group-wrapper{
 width:70%;
 margin:0 auto;
 text-align:center;
 
 position:relative;
}

.group-center h1{
 font-size:45px;
 font-family:arial;
}

.group-center h2{
 font-family:arial;
 font-weight:normal;
 font-size:22.5px;
 margin-top:18px;
}

.group-center h3{
 font-family:arial;
 font-weight:bold;
 font-size:13.5px;
 margin-top:27px;

}

.logo-name{
 display:none;
}   

}



/****** SCREEN: 1115PX ******/
@media screen and (max-width: 705px) {



.group-center h1{
 font-size:40px;
 font-family:arial;
}

.group-center h2{
 font-family:arial;
 font-weight:normal;
 font-size:19.5px;
 margin-top:18px;
}

.group-center h3{
 font-family:arial;
 font-weight:bold;
 font-size:11px;
 margin-top:27px;

}

.logo-name{
 display:none;
}
  
}


/****** SCREEN: 1115PX ******/
@media screen and (max-width: 609px) {



.group-center h1{
 font-size:35px;
 font-family:arial;
}

.group-center h2{
 font-family:arial;
 font-weight:normal;
 font-size:16.5px;
 margin-top:18px;
}

.group-center h3{
 font-family:arial;
 font-weight:bold;
 font-size:9px;
 margin-top:27px;

}

.logo-name{
 display:none;
}


 
   
}


/****** SCREEN: 1115PX ******/
@media screen and (max-width: 609px) {

.group-center h1{
 font-size:30px;
 font-family:arial;
}

.group-center h2{
 font-family:arial;
 font-weight:normal;
 font-size:13.5px;
 margin-top:18px;
}

.group-center h3{
 font-family:arial;
 font-weight:bold;
 font-size:7px;
 margin-top:27px;

}

.logo-name{
 display:none;
}


}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
 <meta charset=utf-8>
 <title>My website</title>
</head>

<body>

<header id = "header">
 <div class = "group-wrapper">
  <div class = "logo-name">
   <h1>name</h1>
   <h2>info</h2>
  </div>

  <nav id = "nav">
   <ul>
    <li>ABOUT</li>
    <li>PORTFOLIO</li>
    <li>TESTIMONIALS</li>
    <li>ARTICLES</li>
    <li>HIRE S</li>
   </ul>
  </nav>

 </div>
</header>

<div class = "intro-company">
 <div class = "group-center">
  <h1>WordPress / Front-end Developer</h1>
  <h2>Producing high quality responsive websites and exceptional user experience</h2>
  <h3>VIEW PORTFOLIO</h3>
 </div>
</div>

<div class = "main-content">
 <div class ="content-wrapper">
  <img src = "me.png" width = 300 height = 400>
  <h1>I'M <span>......</span>
  AND I'M A FRONT-END<span> WEB DEVELOPER.</span></h1>
  
  <p> test test test test test testtest test test test test testtest test test test test testtest test test test test testtest test test test test testtest test test test test testtest test test test test testtest test test test test testtest test test test test testtest test test test test testtest test test test test test </p>

  <p>test test test test test testtest test test test test testtest test test test test testtest test test test test testtest test test test test testtest test test test test testtest test test test test testtest test test test test testtest test test test test testtest test test test test testtest test test test test test
  </p>

  <p>test test test test test testtest test test test test testtest test test test test testtest test test test test testtest test test test test testtest test test test test testtest test test test test testtest test test test test testtest test test test test test
  </p>
 
 </div>
</div>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: if i understand you right you should set the max-width of the text container to something like 340px;

Comment: You can set a fixed width by adding a pixel width to ".main-content" and ".content-wrapper".  For example, `.main-content, .content-wrapper { width: 900px; margin: 0 auto; }` . But this enable an x-scroll once you narrow the window size.